# Python OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying, in Python 3, to append some data to a file, like this:

```
prueba = open(streamingResultFile, "a")
```

... when I previously declare:

```
streamingResultFile = time.asctime().replace('  ', ' ').replace(' ', '_') + '.txt'
```

... to get a file whose name will be the current time and date, in this format:

```
Tue_Apr_4_03:08:55_2017.txt
```

But I run it, and I get the message in the title complaining about the name of my file not being correct. But if I put something else, like "hello.txt" it works.
Why can't I put that text as the name of my output file?

Comment: Please paste the error message.

Comment: What operating system are you running, and what kind of filesystem are you trying to write to?  Please [edit] your question to include these details (as well as what Paul Back has asked for), and add tags for your OS and filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the allowed filename characters for your operating system.

For example, characters like `\`, `:`, `>`, ... are not allowed in Windows filenames.

See [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names) for details on forbidden characters in Windows/Linux filenames.

Regarding your specific problem: Replacing the colons `:` with other characters should solve the error.

Comment: Yes, I was so busy in the other parts of the program that I didn' t realize the semicolons were the problem. Thanks for pointing out